# JSF Deselect selectOneRadio

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to deselect/uncheck items is `<p:selectOneRadio>` or `<h:selectOneRadio/>`?

```html
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{adminManageBroadcastController.selectedImage}" converter="#{broadcastImageConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{adminManageBroadcastController.fileUploadList}"  var="image"
        itemValue="#{image}"
        itemLabelEscaped="false"
        itemLabel="&lt;img src=&quot;#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}#{image.url}&quot; width=&quot;20&quot; height=&quot;20&quot; alt=&quot;broadcast_img&quot;&gt;"
     />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: You mean manually or what?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, `onclick` event may be. I try to understand as I can do that but generated html doesn't help me to find solution

Comment: If you would just like to uncheck the radio button use JavaScript. But if would like to change the value instantly you could bind an eventhandler on the needed component, set the value on the bean to null when the event fires and do an update on the radiobutton.

Comment: @user1983983 What type event do you suggest for eventhandler?

Comment: Please give some details on what you would like to do.

Comment: @user1983983 When I add some data no one radio is checked (it's ok). But when I set radio I can't click on it and deselect. I need deselect radio and set it value to null  when I click on currentc selected radio. As I understand I can do this if I add prevSelected and currentSelected and in event handler on `click` event, like  `<f:ajax event="click" listener="#{adminManageBroadcastController.deselectImage()}" execute="@this" render="@this"/>`

Comment: Do you want a primefaces answer or a JSF answer

Comment: @Andy Better JSF answer)

Comment: Does this make sense ? Are you having trouble with the setter ?

Comment: Please explain the functional requirement along with your question, otherwise it has no sense at all.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I thought it was self-explanatory. Maybe not, let me reword it.

Comment: @Andy how to deselect a radio button? How: by user input, by request/response (maybe with ajax), when accessing a new page, when selecting another non-shown-in-the-example component, by plain JavaScript (so no managed bean usage at all)? I don't think how this can be answerable at all. There's no real purpose on doing such thing.

Comment: @Andy we won't know for sure.

Comment: Ray, consider updating your post. How would you like to achieve this ? Check Luiggi comments. For my answer this is purely server side and the radioButton is unselected when you click on it the second time after a selection has been made. Is that what you're after ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem right, I think the following should help you. As you would like to deselect the radio-button when it is clicked again you should - as you already said - use an ajax listener which is called on `click` of the radio button.
But first of all you have to save the value of the radio button on each change, so you have to add another eventlistener which submits the value of the radio button on `change`.
When the selected button is now clicked again you can check which button is clicked and then check in your bean if this button is the selected button (if it has the value which is set on the bean). If the button is the selected button you set the referenced value on the bean to `null` and update the `selectOneRadio`.
I do not exactly know whats the structure of your application, so I will try to sketch what I mean in code:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{adminManageBroadcastController.selectedImage}" converter="#{broadcastImageConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{adminManageBroadcastController.fileUploadList}"  var="image"
           itemValue="#{image}"
           itemLabelEscaped="false"
           itemLabel="&lt;img src=&quot;#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}#{image.url}&quot; width=&quot;20&quot; height=&quot;20&quot; alt=&quot;broadcast_img&quot;&gt;"
     />
    <p:ajax event="change" process="@parent" partialSubmit="true"/>
    <p:ajax event="click" process="@this" listener="#{adminManageBroadcastController.deselectImage()}" update="@parent"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Another option would be to do the whole thing using JavaScript.

Comment: I don't understand for what change event. I can get value selectedImageId without it, using just listener of event click.

Comment: When the value is not submitted yet you can not check in the bean whether the clicked radio button was already clicked. So you have to submit it everytime the value of the radiobutton is changing.